# using tail to follow a log and execute a command instantly? Only seems to work by starting a new line

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep, tail, less-unix

I am trying to figure out a command which will enable me to read a log file in real time and execute a command when the string matches?  I am using logkeys and trying to make it when I type a word it immediately triggers a command. This script works, but only when I press enter (start a newline) does it execute, and it seems anything I have found online also requires the press of the enter key to work.  Is there a way to get around this somehow?

```
#/bin/bash
echo Waiting...
string='test'
tail /path/to/logfile -n0 -f | while read line; do
        if [[ $line =~ $string ]]; then
                echo "hello"
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've played with buffering settings to no avail, so my conclusion is that `read` waits for a newline before it finishes. If you instead did `read -n1`, `read` would read exactly one character, which isn't quite what we want either, because then `$line` would always be just that one char.

Unfortunately, `grep` appears to have the same behavior (even with buffering options changed), even with `grep -o`:

```
$ tail logfile -f -n0 | grep -o test &
[1] 25524
$ echo -n test >> logfile
$ echo -n test >> logfile
$ echo test >> logfile
test
test
test
```

I **think** the general solution would be to roll our own "ring buffer grep" search tool that reads character per character into a ring buffer.

Here's my perl version of that, hope it helps. (Save as: `ringgrep.pl`)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

if (!$ARGV[0]) {
    print "Usage: $0 needle\n";
    exit 1;
}
my $needle = $ARGV[0];
my $buffer_len = length($needle);
my @buffer = (0) x $buffer_len;
my $i = 0;
my $input;

while(sysread(STDIN, $input, 1)) {
    $buffer[$i] = $input;
    my $string = join("", @buffer);
    $string = (($i+1)%$buffer_len == 0 ? "" : substr($string, $i-$buffer_len+1)) . substr($string, 0, $i+1);
    # print "string is: $string\n";
    if ($string =~ /$needle/) {
        print "got test!\n";
        @buffer = (0) x $buffer_len;
        $i = 0
    } else {
        $i = (++$i) % $buffer_len
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$ chmod +x ringgrep.pl
$ tail logfile -n0 -f | ./ringgrep.pl "this is a test" &
[1] 25756
$ echo -n "test" >> logfile
$ echo -n "test" >> logfile
$ echo -n "test" >> logfile
$ echo -n "test" >> logfile
$ echo -n "this is a test" >> logfile
got test!
$ echo -n "this is a test" >> logfile
got test!
$ echo -n "this is a test" >> logfile
got test!
$ (echo -n t; echo -n h; echo -n i; echo -n s; echo -n ' '; echo -n i; echo -n s; echo -n ' '; echo -n a; echo -n ' '; echo -n t; echo -n e; echo -n s; echo -n t) >> logfile
got test!
```

Comment: It's of course entirely possible to write this in bash, but maybe there's a better way to do this anyway.